# Python, Matrix of matrixs

Tags: python, list, matrix

I need to create a matrix whose elements contain matrix and internal matrixes have numbers.

How would I access the internal matrices, and how to the numbers that contain those matrixes.

```
ext_matrix = []
int_matrixes = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
ext_matrix.append(int_matrixes)
```

I tried this solution but if I need an external 2x2 matrix or internal 2x2 it doesn't work

Comment: You can use indexing to index into the various levels, for example: `ext_matrix[0][1][2]`

Comment: or just use multidimensional ndarray from numpy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an index to get items.

```
ext_matrix = [] 
int_matrixes = [[0,1,2],[10,11,12],[20,21,22]]
ext_matrix.append(int_matrixes)

ext_matrix2 = []
ext_matrix2.extend(int_matrixes)

## [[[0, 1, 2], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22]]]
print(ext_matrix)

## [20, 21, 22]
print(ext_matrix[0][2])

## 21
print(ext_matrix[0][2][1])

## [[0, 1, 2], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22]]
print(ext_matrix2)

## [20, 21, 22]
print(ext_matrix2[2])

## 21
print(ext_matrix2[2][1])
```

Or you can use ndarray from numpy:

```
import numpy as np

ext_matrix = np.array([[ 0, 1, 2],
                       [10, 11, 12],
                       [20, 21, 22]])

## [[ 0  1  2]
##  [10 11 12]
##  [20 21 22]]
print(ext_matrix)

## [20 21 22]
print(ext_matrix[2])

## 21
print(ext_matrix[2][1])
```